# How to store State Data in a data model in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

So forgive me with this dumb question, as I am learning SwiftUI, and managing state is new to me.

I am building an app that is going through a series of steps, and in each step I want to collect data on each view and store it in a datamodel to use in an API later.

I have a file called Data

```
import SwiftUI

struct Data {
    @Binding var region: String
}
```

pretty simple. I basically want this data to be accessed by the views, and then eventually the API call that will be made at the end of the selection process.

In one view, a user will select the region card.

```
    struct RegionView: View {
        @State var regionSelected: String = ""
        
        var body: some View {
            //Some code
                            RegionGroups { selected in
                                            regionSelected = selected
                                            Data(region: $regionSelected)
                                        }
                            
//Some more Code
```

So at this point im not sure if this is actually setting the state in the model or not.

later on there will be a confirmation page that will display several different state variables.

I am getting an error when I make a temp one.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Temp: View {
    @ObservedObject var regionSelected = Data()

    var body: some View {
        Text(Data.region)
    }
}

struct Temp_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Temp()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Data` needs to be a class, with `region` published like this:

```
class Data: ObservableObject {
    @Published var region: String = ""
}
```

then in `RegionView`:

```
struct RegionView: View {
    // If this is your first instantiation, use @StateObject, otherwise
    // pass Data to an @ObservedObject or Data.region to a @Binding
    @StateObject var data = Data()
    
    var body: some View {
        //Some code
                        RegionGroups { selected in
                                        data.region = selected
                                    }
```

edit:

With your update to `Temp`, you have a common error. If you declare `@ObservedObject var regionSelected = Data()` you have instantiated a new and different object, not the one from `RegionView`. If you are just displaying the data, and not changing it in `Temp`, is should look like this:

struct Temp: View {
let regionSelected: String

```
var body: some View {
    Text(regionSelected)
}
```

}

and you would call it like this:

Temp(data.region)

I also correct a Glaring error in my original code. Please see the updated `RegionView`.

Lastly, I don't think you are getting the concept of an MRE. We should be able to take what you post and run it ourselves in Xcode. This allows us to make sure everything is correct, and we understand the issue you are posting about.

Comment: Ok, I understand what your saying... so lets say 3-4 views from now when I want to show a confirmation page, how do I show this text? When I ran a quick test of this, I get nstance member 'region' cannot be used on type 'Data'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Comment: You did not include  a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so it is difficult to follow down the rabbit hole. If you update your question with an MRE, we can go from there. It all depends on how you got there as there are several options, but no way to recommend any without the code and app structure.

Comment: Also, have you gone through [Apple's Tutorials?](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) This sort of thing is explained in there pretty well.

Comment: Ya, I did, I confused myself, your solution did work for passing the data along. I updated the initial with what im talking about. I am eventually going to collect pieces of user data to  send into an API, not just region.. at the end of the process the user will validate everything, on that page I will display everything they selected, so I want to be able to call that variable. I made a Temp page, so I can learn this, and I copied that temp page in original post.

Comment: ok, using Data.region does not work, but doing regionSelected.region no longer gives error. However, in the next view I am using a text object that is doing Data.region and it does not show the state value... so clearly im doing something wrong

Comment: Ok great, I just caught your edits... This work beautifully! thank you I learned a lot from this.

Comment: The ONLY question I would like to add, this works great if your calling 1 piece of data. Eventually im going to have about 10 views asking questions and storing data to the model, the last screen will display each answer. Can you not call the entire model and display each piece of data?

Comment: If you are using the same instance, the model doesn't care. And again, it depends on what you do in the last screen. If it is simply display, with no change to the model, you can send it in with a `let data: Data`. But again, these answers depend upon what you are actually doing, which is why the MRE is so important.

Comment: its simply a display. Upon pushing a button im going to do an API call with that data

Comment: Then the above will work.